# Is there a way to refresh an array of SQLAlchemy objects?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am trying to seed my Postgres database using the below python function

```
def seed_users(db: Session, number: int = 50):
    users = []
    for _ in range(number):
        user_seed = {
            'first_name': f.first_name(),
            'last_name': f.last_name(),
            'email_address': f.ascii_company_email()
        }
        users.append(models.User(**user_seed))

    db.bulk_save_objects(users)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(users)
    return users
```

f is a Faker object. But it throws `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.list' is not mapped` error.

How can I refresh all the newly created rows?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @KR32 sadly I have not. I will have another crack at it again.

Comment: also faced this problem. the solution below is not suitable because it makes a separate request for each object

Answer (score 3):

I know that this answer may be a little late, but I found that refresh should be performed on each object seperately.

```
for user in users:
    db.refresh(user)
```

I had the same issue and this did the trick!

Comment: It works, but it’s very inefficient because it issues a separate query for each object.

Answer (score 1):

To perform a bulk refresh in SQLAlchemy 2.0 you can use the [populate_existing](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/api.html#populate-existing) execution option on a query that will return the instances that you wish to refresh.

```py
with Session() as s:
    users = s.scalars(sa.select(User)).all()
    # Let's assume some other process has updated our users rows.
    # commit (or rollback) to ensure we can see the results of the other transaction
    s.commit()
    s.execute(sa.select(User).execution_options(populate_existing=True))
    # the session will now contain updated data.
```

In the specific case in the question, the legacy bulk [save_bulk_objects](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.bulk_save_objects) method doesn't populate the session, so there is nothing to "refresh". If this method must be used, the database must be queried directly to retrieve the objects. (There is also the option of setting  `return_defaults=True` in the `bulk_insert_objects` call, but the performance hit probably defeats the purpose of doing a bulk insert in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an answer I liked online, so I will add what I came up with here for others in case you like it too.

What I did was create a bulk insert statement as specified here in the 2.0 docs and have it return the created instances.

This means that I don't need to refresh anything, because I didn't use the `session.add(...)` syntax! https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#getting-new-objects-with-returning

```py
class UserModel(sqlalchemy.DeclarativeBase): ...


async def create_many_users(data: Sequence[dict]):
    instances = [UserModel(**item) for item in data]
    results = await session.scalars(insert(User).returning(User).values(instances))

    # Flush commands to DB (within transaction) so we can refresh instance from DB
    await session.flush()
    return results.all()
```

And honestly, I'm finding myself more and more using this syntax instead of the session.add stuff just because of how much more flexible it is. Think updates too. I do the same thing there and there's no need for inefficient 'refreshes'.

Hope this helps!